# How to set full control permission for file and folder on Windows with cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, permissions, icacls, cacls

I'm trying this below. Than read, write & execute permission can stop, but file rename I can't stop with this command.

```
CACLS files /e /p {USERNAME}:{PERMISSION}
```

Where,

- /p : Set new permission
- /e : Edit permission and kept old permission as it is i.e. edit ACL instead of replacing it.
- {USERNAME} : Name of user
- {PERMISSION} : Permission can be:

  - R - Read
  - W - Write
  - C - Change (write)
  - F - Full control

For example grant Rocky Full (F) control with following command (type at Windows command prompt):

```
C:> CACLS files /e /p rocky:f
```

Read complete help by typing the following command:

```
C:> cacls /?
```

Comment: On Windows 10, the output from `C:>cacls /?` contains `NOTE: Cacls is now deprecated, please use Icacls.`

Answer (score 0):

below is a working sample that i use

```
ICACLS *.* /setowner "authenticated users" /T /C
```

now use the command ICALS
/grant or /deny the permission
then username